# working with arrays inside a loop in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have the following php code that displays csv data on the browser:

```
$file1 = file('SpreadsheetA.csv',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
foreach($file1 as $val)
{
    echo $val;
}
```

the above outputs all the data in the csv file as a string:

```
Matter Number,Amount,Currency,Company Code100,2000,USD,310101,23000,EUR,110102,120,GBP,120103,10000,USD,310
```

if i want to capture the above as an array, this is what i do:

```
foreach($file1 as $val)
    {
        var_dump(array($val));
    }
```

and this is the output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(42) "Matter Number,Amount,Currency,Company Code"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(16) "100,2000,USD,310"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(17) "101,23000,EUR,110"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(15) "102,120,GBP,120"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(17) "103,10000,USD,310"
}
```

as shown, each string is captured as an array..my wish is to capture all strings under a single array as follows:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(42) "Matter Number,Amount,Currency,Company Code"
  [1]=>
  string(16) "100,2000,USD,310"
  [2]=>
  string(17) "101,23000,EUR,110"
  [3]=>
  string(15) "102,120,GBP,120"
  [4]=>
  string(17) "103,10000,USD,310"
}
```

how would i accomplish the above(inside the foreach loop)??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should loop your arrays into `$file` and fill another array with the string values

try this code:

```
$output = array();
foreach ($file1 as $val) {
    $output[] = $val[0];
}

var_dump(array($output));
```

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\masterclass\comparecsvfiles\try1.php on line 13

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\masterclass\comparecsvfiles\try1.php on line 13

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\masterclass\comparecsvfiles\try1.php on line 13

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\masterclass\comparecsvfiles\try1.php on line 13

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\masterclass\comparecsvfiles\try1.php 
array(1) { [0]=> array(0) { } }

Comment: displays:array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "M"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [4]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}

Comment: thanks ponciste.this works:    $output = array();
foreach ($file1 as $val) {
    $output[] = $val;
}

var_dump(array($output));

Comment: i simply removed the [] in $val and left it as $output[] = $val;

Comment: ah ok, but it's weird since your output shows that `var_dump(array($val));` are all arrays. By the way glad it working somehow :)